# Send dynamic array in form via $_POST to html email

Tags: php, forms, post, html-email

This title might not describe my question too well but I was unsure how to name this post... Anyways, I have a form that has dynamically generated input boxes that pulls the last 4 years with the following:

```
<?php
    $current_date = new DateTime();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
        $current_date->modify('-1 year');
        $date_string = $current_date->format('Y')
?>

<fieldset name="gross_sales">
    <input type="number" name="year_brand_gross[<?php echo $date_string; ?>]" placeholder="Gross Sales for <?php echo $date_string; ?>">
</fieldset>

<?php
} // end while
?>
```

And once the user clicks submit the form data is processed via my process.php file that contains the following:

```
$year_brand_gross[1] = $_POST['year_brand_gross'][1];
$year_brand_gross[2] = $_POST['year_brand_gross'][2];
$year_brand_gross[3] = $_POST['year_brand_gross'][3];
$year_brand_gross[4] = $_POST['year_brand_gross'][4];
```

Now I'm pretty sure the above part is not right. So this is my question... How would I get the info from these inputs into my email that's sent since their created by an array and not "actually" there. Here's a stripped down version of my html email that's sent which I'm pretty sure is also wrong since the above code is incorrect:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Gross Sales:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{$year_brand_gross[1]}</td>
        <td>{$year_brand_gross[2]}</td>
        <td>{$year_brand_gross[3]}</td>
        <td>{$year_brand_gross[4]}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can we see the whole code? That might help.

Comment: `$_POST['year_brand_gross'][1]` should be changed to `$_POST['year_brand_gross'][2012]`

Comment: Then the code would need updated every year. We did it this way so that the code would not need updating. And @tntu the whole code is about 3,000 lines and semi-confidential. I have posted all the necessary code.

Answer (score 1):

Your form would actually look like

```
<input type="number" name="year_brand_gross[2012]" ... />
<input type="number" name="year_brand_gross[2011]" ... />
<input type="number" name="year_brand_gross[2010]" ... />
etc...
```

That means you need to use

```
$_POST['year_brand_gross'][2012]
$_POST['year_brand_gross'][2011]
$_POST['year_brand_gross'][2010]
etc...
```

on the server.

Comment: Hey Marc, thanks for your input! But I'm afraid this won't work. We used an array that dynamically made an input for the last 4 years so that we wouldn't have to update the code every year. So this year it would show 2013-2009 whereas next year it would show 2014-2010...

Comment: I understand what the php code "prints" when a user views it. The problem is since we're using dynamically generated inputs I'm not sure what goes where the # signs are in the following since it can't actually be a year: $year_brand_gross# = $_POST['year_brand-gross'][#]

Comment: so do `foreach($_POST['year_brand_gross'] as $year => $value)`. you'll get the embedded year and its associated value, without caring WHAT years they are

Comment: Ok so I can replace the following: $year_brand_gross[1] = $_POST['year_brand_gross'][1];
$year_brand_gross[2] = $_POST['year_brand_gross'][2];
$year_brand_gross[3] = $_POST['year_brand_gross'][3];
$year_brand_gross[4] = $_POST['year_brand_gross'][4]; with what you posted above?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST['year_brand_gross'] AS $yeah => $value) {
  // use $year and $value variables to do whatever
  // this code will execute once for each values in $_POST['year_brand_gross'].
  // note: print_r($_POST);
  // $_POST is an array, same for $_GET and so on
}
```